# A name attribut that can't be updated - javascript

Tags: javascript

It is a script in javascript that add a `<div></div>` and add an id, a class, html.. I want to add name attribut too and my code doesn't works, but I wonder why..

There https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/DOM/element I have seen that `element.name = 'newname';` can edit it..

```
function newgroup() {
    var e = document.getElementsByName('group');
    var nb = e.length + 1
    div = document.createElement("div");
    div.id = 'group'+nb;
    div.className = 'panel_drop';
    div.name = '1';
    div.innerHTML = '<h5>Group '+nb+'</h5>';
    div.innerHTML += '<div class=\'drop_zone\'></div>';
    document.getElementById('groups').appendChild(div);

}
```

Comment: Why?  The name attribute is deprecated on all but form elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `name` attribute of an HTML element is not mapped to the `name` property of the corresponding DOM element for all elements, but only for certain types of elements, and DIV elements are not one of them.

You can check for which types of HTML elements the `name` attribute is specified here: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage//section-index.html#attributes-1

Since the HTML standard doesn't specify a `name` attribute for DIV elements, my recommendation is to *not* use such an attribute/property on DIV elements. If you need to attach additional information to your DIV elements, consider `data-*` attributes.

Answer (score 3):

```
div.setAttribute('name', '1');
```

The fact that *div.getAttribute('class')* is also exported as a *convenience function* as the *className* property (with an impilicit setter and getter) doesn't mean that it is a consistent way to handle DOM node property names.

BTW, consider using a javascript framework, like jQuery, Prototype, MooTools or YUI, helps on the long run...

For example with Jquery you can have easily a finer control on attributes by [changing them](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) or [removing them](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/)